# Page header (Chapter name and page number) cover table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, header-footer

I am a bit clueless as how to approach this problem and I hope some of you might be able to help me. As seen in the attached screenshot, the table I have in landscape mode collide with the chapter name and page number (inside red square). What I want is either to remove the page number/chapter name for the pages covered by the table, or to shift the table so that it does not conflict with the header.

[image: Table overlapping with header (see within red square)]

Best regards,
Henrik

Code used for table:

```
    \begin{landscape}
    \section{Rock-Eval Data}
    Rock-Eval data. Any missing values in hydrogen and oxygen index is due to either negative or missing TOC values.

    \begin{footnotesize}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{ccccccccc}

    \caption{Rock-Eval data.}\\
    \toprule
    \label{tab:retable}
    \textbf{Level (m)} & \textbf{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{S$2$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{S$3$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{T$_{Max}$ (\degree{C})} & \textbf{PI (wt ratio)} & \textbf{Hydrogen Index (mg HC/g TOC)} & \textbf{Oxygen Index (mg HC/g TOC)} &\textbf{Powder Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{9}{c}%{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Level (m)} & \textbf{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{S$2$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{S$3$ (mg/g)} & \textbf{T$_{Max}$ (\degree{C})} & \textbf{PI (wt ratio)} & \textbf{Hydrogen Index (mg HC/g TOC)} & \textbf{Oxygen Index (mg HC/g TOC)} &\textbf{Powder Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    DATA GOES HERE
    $11.75$  & $0$    & $0$     & $0.62$  & $513$   & $0$     &          &           & Light Grey \\

    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{footnotesize}
    \end{landscape}
```

Comment: Plase, provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I don't know dimensions of the page and what packages you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `makecell`. It allows for line breaks in `\thead` cells  and a common formatting. Note `SIunitx` would help to typeset units and have a nice formatting of numbers in tables. Also, there is no `footnotesize` environment, as far as I know, only a `\footnotesize` switch. Anyway, you can type the table in `\normalsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, caption, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \section{Rock-Eval Data}
    Rock-Eval data. Any missing values in hydrogen and oxygen index is due to either negative or missing TOC values.
    \begin{center}%
    \begin{longtable}{ccccccccc}
    \caption{Rock-Eval data.}
    \label{tab:retable}\\
    \toprule
    \thead{Level \\(m)} & \thead{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$2$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$3$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{$\mathbf T_\text{Max}$\\ (\si{\celsius})}
     & \thead{PI\\ (wt ratio)} & \thead{Hydrogen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} & \thead{Oxygen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} &\thead{Powder\\ Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %\multicolumn{9}{c}%{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    \thead{Level \\(m)} & \thead{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$2$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$3$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{$T_\text{Max}$\\ (\si{\celsius})}
     & \thead{PI\\ (wt ratio)} & \thead{Hydrogen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} & \thead{Oxygen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} &\thead{Powder\\ Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    %%DATA GOES HERE
    $11.75$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0.62$ & $513$ & $0$ & & & Light Grey \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{landscape}

    \end{document} 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, ltablex, caption, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \section{Rock-Eval Data}
    Rock-Eval data. Any missing values in hydrogen and oxygen index is due to either negative or missing TOC values.
    \begin{center}%
    \begin{longtable}{ccccccccc}
    \caption{Rock-Eval data.}
    \label{tab:retable}\\
    \toprule
    \thead{Level \\(m)} & \thead{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$2$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$3$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{$\mathbf T_\text{Max}$\\ (\si{\celsius})}
     & \thead{PI\\ (wt ratio)} & \thead{Hydrogen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} & \thead{Oxygen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} &\thead{Powder\\ Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %\multicolumn{9}{c}%{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    \thead{Level \\(m)} & \thead{S$1$ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$2$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{S$3$\\ (mg/g)} & \thead{$T_\text{Max}$\\ (\si{\celsius})}
     & \thead{PI\\ (wt ratio)} & \thead{Hydrogen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} & \thead{Oxygen Index\\ (mg HC/g TOC)} &\thead{Powder\\ Colour}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}}\\
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    %%DATA GOES HERE
    $11.75$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0.62$ & $513$ & $0$ & & & Light Grey \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]